# Python unable to import package in the package

Tags: python

I'm currently using this repository https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition-Python for studying. I want to run the script, but I got an error, for example,  `Unable to import 'chapter_04.binary_search_tree'` when I try to run `python3 chapter_04/p09_bst_sequences.py`.

Here is the code of `chapter_04/p09_bst_sequences.py`.

```
from chapter_04.binary_search_tree import BinarySearchTree

# code continues...
```

I guess this error is pretty normal because `p09_bst_sequences.py` file is already at `chapter_04` directory. As I guessed, if I rewrite the file like below, I actually can run normally.

```
from binary_search_tree import BinarySearchTree #changed

# code continues...
```

However, this repository is pretty big and used by a decent amount of people, so I assume these codes are not mistakes or anything. I think I'm just misunderstanding something. Please tell me about that.

Comment: Imports are relative to the working directory. I assume the code is supposed to be run from the parent directory, which would make the imports correct

Comment: Yeah just run it from the parent directory of the repository as for example `python chapter_04/binary_search_tree.py` should probably work

Comment: @LukasThaler Thanks for the comment! You mean I should go parent directory and then run like `python3 chapter_04/p09_bst_sequences.py`? Like I already wrote above, I tried that and then go that error message.

Comment: @RolvApneseth Thanks for your advice. Yeah, that's exactly what I thought. And I tried like I wrote above and then got that error. Anyway, really appreciate your advice.

Comment: For all intents and purposes `python3 chapter_04/p09_bst_sequences.py` has to work from the parent directory, so please double check that you are in fact in the correct directory when running the command. Your working directory does not have to be `chapter04` but one level higher

Comment: @LukasThaler @RolvApneseth Sorry guys, replies for both of you up there were wrong. When I retried as you guys said, the result became different. Output says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chapter_04'`. I mean it's still not working, but thanks for giving me some knowledge like "_Imports are relative to the working directory_". Appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like the repo is actually missing `__init__.py`, try creating a file called that in the chapter_04 directory and try again (it can be blank python just needs it to know it is a module)

Comment: Either way you can raise an issue on the repo and ask for clarity on how they reccomend you to run it. I doubt it's very important though since they are just answers to coding problems